# php tag inside html - body of phpmailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

How can I add a php tag inside the mail body i.e., adding with html tag?

The following code is not working:

```
$mail->Body = '<h1 style="font-family: Arial;">Enquiry Details</h1>'.<?php $message;?>.'<h1>Enquiry 2</h1>'
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
$mail->Body = 
     '<h1 style="font-family: Arial;">Enquiry Details</h1>' .
     $message .
     '<h1>Enquiry 2</h1>';
```

Since you are already inside `<?php` `?>` block, you do not need to re-declare php open/close tags until you have closed the previous open tag.  (Formatted the above code so it's all visible without scrolling)

Comment: Hi, I tried your code. Again it shows HTTP ERROR 500 on the browser

Comment: @Rajesh please post the log relevant to the attempt.  Sounds like there are other errors you need to correct -- not just this one line.

Comment: Hi, If i remove '.$message.', it works. So i think this is the issue

Comment: @Rajesh try to turn on php error reporting to see errors : `error_reporting(-1);`  I think your `$message` is not a string! maybe its an array

Comment: I removed a stray `;` from `$message; .`   making it `$message .`.   Try now.  Also, your error log should have made that super easy to spot.

Comment: Hi. It works. After removing the stray also error was there. But I realized that I had a duplicate variable $mail. i changed that to $email. It works now. Thank you